# Compute the value of π using the following series (Matlab conversion)

Tags: python, type-conversion, series, pi

I just started using Python and can't really get the hang of it..

I wrote the code in **Matlab** but is hard to covert it the right way in **Python**.

[image]

Could you please help?

```
 x=0;
    for i=1:1000
         x=x+(1/((((2*i)-1)^2)*(((2*i)+1^2))));
         z=sqrt((x*16)+8);
         error=abs(z-pi);
         if (error < 10^-8)
            i
            break
         end
    end
```

Thank you

Comment: You forgot a parenthesis !  ((2*i+1)^2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import math
```

...

```
x = 0
for i in range(1,1001):
    x = x + (1 / (((2 * i - 1) ** 2) * ((2 * i + 1) ** 2)))
    z = math.sqrt((x * 16) + 8)
    error = abs(z - math.pi)
    if error < 10 ** -8:
        print(i)
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but when I calculate it in mathlab and also by hand, I get the result as being i= 174, and in this code it results that i=999. Could you please check the image maybe I miscalculated something? thank you for your help

Comment: My bad it was range(1,1001) and not range(1,1000).
But when I execute your code in mathlab, at the end of the loop I got i = 1000

Comment: I've edited my code try it, a parenthesis was missing

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I got the right answer now.

Answer (score 2):

The following segment of code is equivalent to what you have written in Matlab.

```
from math import pi, sqrt

x = 0
error_tolerance = 1e-8

for i in range(1, 1001):
    x += 1 / (((2 * i - 1) ** 2) * ((2 * i + 1) ** 2))
    z = sqrt((x * 16) + 8)
    error = abs(z - pi)
    if error < error_tolerance:
        print(i)
        break
```

The key differences in between Python and Matlab that can be seen in this code are:

- ***Indentation:*** For loops, while loops, if statements, function definitions, etc. are isolated using correct indentation instead of a starting keyword and `end`.  You can see that the for loop statement ends with a colon, and everything inside the for loop has been indented by a tab OR 4 spaces.  The `break` keyword is further indented because it only executes when the error is less than the specified tolerance.
- ***Operators:*** You can see that the raised power symbol `^` has been replaced with `**`.  This is because `^` represents a bitwise XOR operation.  You may also notice that `x += ...` has been used instead of `x = x + ...`.  These two statements are equivalent, the first way is just more concise.
- ***Semicolons:*** Python does not require the use of semicolons to mute a variable/constant.  Instead, to find out what the value of the variable is, simply use the `print(...)` statement.
- ***For loops:*** Instead of just iterating over a linear sequence like Matlab does, in Python each for loop will iterate over the next item in a specified iterable sequence.  In this case, we have used the built-in `range` function to generate a list of integers from 1 to 1000, and in each loop `i` will be set to the next value in this linear sequence.
- ***Non built-in functions:*** Python's base set of built-ins does not contain a `sqrt` function or `pi` constant definition.  Instead these have been separated into a separate module named `math` alongside many other mathematical functions such as `sin`, `cosine`, etc..
- ***Brackets around if-conditions:*** You can use brackets around if statement conditions.  However, for simple conditions such as this one, they are not necessary.

There are **many** more differences between the two languages, I have just highlighted the most noticeable differences between the Matlab code you have provided and its Python equivalent.  To find out more about Python I suggest looking at online tutorials, and you can find plenty of answers to commonly asked questions through a Google search or on this site.

**Edit:** I noticed a slight error in your implementation of the mathematical sequence, and have updated it to match the formula provided in your link.  I also removed unnecessary brackets

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarifications and such a great detailed answer. I will watch some tutorials for a better understanding of how python works.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Good luck!